# Sony Vaio Duo 11 SVD1121X9EB liquid in lcd screen

Tags: lcd, sony-vaio, laptop-display

The screen of my sony convertible ultrabook shows some strange shape in the lower left corner for a while which is making the screen seem a bit transparent and is gradually growing (a few mm a week). Also for a few days the upper left croner shows two "bubble" shapes that also grow (a few mm a day). The screen itself is still working but I'd like to ask here what this is (the laptop never got wet so if it is some liquid inside then it must come from the inside) and what I can do about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

my Vaio Duo 11 have the same issue. The problem is that the LCD screen is glued to the touch, you see the screen unglued and probably you have bubbles also, if not now in a soon time you have this bubbless. The only solution that I find is the replacement of the Screen. I want to try an UV lamp, because the glue in the screen of some cellphones cure under UV light. I comment the results of this test when done.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you clarify the statement *"he LCD screen is glued to the touch"*.

Comment: I think the statement refers to the fact that the LCD panel and the touch panel are glued together.

Comment: Any progress? It seems that one can buy screen glue from ebay or amazon. A reasonable but probably time-demanding solution with the risk of breaking things would be to try to disassemble the screen/tft/touch digitizer assembly and re-glue it. Anybody tried this?